# PHP getting string between two delimeters

Tags: php, html, regex, string, parsing

I am trying to grab the href values from the following string:

```
<td valign="top" width="300"class="topborder"><a href="/path/to/somewhere" class="bigger">random1</a><br/>
<td valign="top" width="300"class="topborder"><a href="/path/to/somewhere2" class="bigger">random2</a><br/>
```

In this case, I should get "/path/to/somewhere" and "/path/to/somewhere2"

I tried to do the following, but I just get empty strings.

```
$htmlc = str_replace(' ', '', $htmlc);
//$htmlc contains the string I am parsing with the spaces removed
preg_match_all('/width=\"300\"class=\"topborder\"><ahref=\"([^\"class=\"bigger\"]+)/', $htmlc, $hrefvals);
```

$hrefvals contains empty strings at this point. What am I doing wrong in my preg_match_all?

Comment: Well your `ahref=` should be `a href=` surely?

Comment: There's no space between a and href in ahref, is this intended?

Comment: I actually remove the spaces before hand, sorry forgot to copy that into the question.

Comment: removing the spaces is a bad idea (and a bad idea for what you are trying to do).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is DOM and XPath. Regular expressions were not designed for HTML parsing.

```
<?php
$html = <<<HTML
<td valign="top" width="300"class="topborder"><a href="/path/to/somewhere" class="bigger">random1</a><br/>
<td valign="top" width="300"class="topborder"><a href="/path/to/somewhere2" class="bigger">random2</a><br/>
HTML;
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
// replace with @$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://...') with you want to parse an URL
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$links = array_map(function ($node) {
        return $node->getAttribute('href');
    }, iterator_to_array($xpath->query("//td[@class='topborder']/a[@class='bigger']")));
var_dump($links);
```

This gave me the following:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(18) "/path/to/somewhere"
  [1]=>
  string(19) "/path/to/somewhere2"
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the string I posted is just a small portion of the whole string. The whole string contains many other href values with the class topborder which I don't want. I need the href values which not only have the class "topborder" for the td but also the class "bigger" for the href. Do you know how to incorporate that in your answer?

Comment: @SKLAK I've updated my answer. Just append `[@class='bigger']` to the end of `$xpath->query()` expression. Can you tell me if it worked for you? :)

Comment: @SKLAK You're welcome! Glad I was able to help you. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try a pattern like this

```
/width=\"300\"class=\"topborder\"><ahref=\"(.*?)"/
```

`"(.*?)"` will match any character but is "lazy". That means once it finds the first `"` after the group (in this case: end of the `href` tag), the group will end

[demo](http://3v4l.org/BgebB)

Comment: Nevermind, I was copying the pattern incorrectly. This works too but grabs some unneeded href values. I think the DOM and XPath answer is more efficient and cleaner. Regardless, you did answer what I asked correctly. thanks.

Comment: I don't know about the efficiency but it is indeed cleaner, way better to refactor and to modify/use in the future. So good choice ;)

Answer (score 0):

or you could try:

```
$htmlc = '
<td valign="top" width="300"class="topborder"><a href="/path/to/somewhere" class="bigger">random1</a><br/>
<td valign="top" width="300"class="topborder"><a href="/path/to/somewhere2" class="bigger">random2</a><br/>
';

preg_match_all('~(?<=<a\shref=")[^"]*~', $htmlc, $hrefvals);
var_dump($hrefvals);
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    alert($("#blah").attr("href"));
  });
});
</script>
```

Then...

```
<a href="http://www.blah.com" id="blah">Blah</a></p>
<button>Show href Value</button>
```

Is this what you mean?

Comment: hmm, not exactly. I am trying to parse a string which contains the html of another page and grabbing the href values from that html.